# searching for a pattern and deleting the whole line that contains it

Tags: bash, unix

having trouble here, I need to search for a pattern and then delete the whole line that its contained in, from a separate file.

for example, if I search "mike" in a file that contains

mike:24

sally:12

chris:54

it will delete the whole line for mike

Heres the script i have so far

```
clear
        tput cup 2 5; echo "Enter pattern to search record(s) to be deleted: "
        tput cup 2 55; read pattern
        tput cup 4 5; printf "Following records found:\n"
        cat  $fileName | grep -i "$pattern"
        printf "Do you want to delete (yes/no): "
        read choice
        case "$choice" in
            yes|Yes)
            echo "$r1 Deleting records $r2"
            echo "$(grep -v "$pattern" $fileName)" > $fileName
            ;;
            *)  echo "Returning.."
            ;;
        esac
        ;;
```

Comment: Where exactly you're having trouble?

Comment: @oguz ismail Its not deleting the line from the file

Comment: Works fine here with a *simple* pattern. Though the last `;;` causes a syntax error.

Comment: How so? deleting the last ;; gave a syntax error for me

Comment: I don't know. That last `;;` isn't required at all, does your actual script look different than the one in the question?

Answer (score 1):

The 'sed' command with the -i option will edit the file in place:

```
sed -i "/mike/d"  $fileName
```

will delete all lines containing 'mike' in $filename.  Also, sed provides some powerful editing modes like deleting lines between delimiters, etc.

EDIT 1: use with bash variables:

```
# REGEX example for mike and Mike anchored to beginning of line
# Any simple string or REGEX pattern will work
export pattern="^[mM]ike"   
sed -i "/${pattern}/d" $fileName
```

$fileName before:

```
James Jones
Mike Jones
mike Jones
Mikeala Jones
Mary Jones
Mary Mike
```

$fileName After:

```
James Jones
Mary Jones
Mary Mike
```

The last line is still present because the '^' anchored the pattern to the beginning of the line and Mike is not at the beginning of the line in the last line

Note also that the pattern did not contain a space to mach os Mikeala is also matched

Comment: would that work with $pattern? tried that still wont delete it

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using following command:

```
grep -v "mike" filename
```

And redirect the output to another file.